# How do I add more than one item in orderable document list in sanity

Tags: schema, sanity

I added 2 schema - 'abouts' and 'works'. In the Sanity dashboard, it is only showing the 'works' document list since I added it in the structure plugin...

```
import {defineConfig, isDev} from 'sanity'
import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision'
import {deskTool, StructureBuilder} from 'sanity/desk'
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas'
import {getStartedPlugin} from './plugins/sanity-plugin-tutorial'
import {orderableDocumentListDeskItem} from '@sanity/orderable-document-list'
import {orderRankField, orderRankOrdering} from '@sanity/orderable-document-list'


const devOnlyPlugins = [getStartedPlugin()]

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'navy-whale',

  projectId: 'o3m70o57',
  dataset: 'production',

  plugins: [deskTool(
    {
      structure: (S, context) => { 
          return  S.list()
              .title('Content')
              .items([
                  // Minimum required configuration
                  orderableDocumentListDeskItem({type:'works', S, context}),])
      },
  }
  ), visionTool(), ...(isDev ? devOnlyPlugins : [])],

  schema: {
    types: (schemaTypes) => {
      return [
          ...schemaTypes, 
          {
              name: "abouts",
              title: "Abouts",
              type: "document",
              // Optional: The plugin also exports a set of 'orderings' for use in other Document Lists
              // https://www.sanity.io/docs/sort-orders
              orderings: [orderRankOrdering],
              fields: [
                {
                  name:'title',
                  title:'Title',
                  type:'string',
                  
              },
              {
                  name:'description',
                  title:'Description',
                  type:'string'
              },
              {
                  name:'imgUrl',
                  title:'ImgUrl',
                  type: 'image',
                  options: {
                    hotspot: true,
                  },
              },
                  // Minimum required configuration
                  orderRankField({ type: "abouts"}),

                  // ...all other fields
              ],
          },
          {
            name: 'works',
            title: 'Works',
            type: "document",
            // Optional: The plugin also exports a set of 'orderings' for use in other Document Lists
            // https://www.sanity.io/docs/sort-orders
            orderings: [orderRankOrdering],
            fields: [
              {
                name: 'title',
                title: 'Title',
                type: 'string',
              },
            
              {
                name: 'description',
                title: 'Description',
                type: 'string',
              },
              {
                name: 'projectLink',
                title: 'Project Link',
                type: 'string',
              },
              {
                name: 'codeLink',
                title: 'Code Link',
                type: 'string',
              },
              {
                name: 'imgUrl',
                title: 'ImageUrl',
                type: 'image',
                options: {
                  hotspot: true,
                },
              },
           
              {
                name: 'tags',
                title: 'Tags',
               type:'array',
               of: [
                 {
                   name:'tag',
                   title:'Tag',
                   type:'string'
                 }
               ]
              },
                // Minimum required configuration
                orderRankField({ type: "works"}),

                // ...all other fields
            ],
        },
      ]
  },
  },
})
```

I want to add the 'about' so that it can show both lists
[screenshot of Sanity showing only 'works' list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTEsg.png)

```
.items([
                  // Minimum required configuration
                  orderableDocumentListDeskItem({type:'works', S, context}),])
```